# Fetch Reviews from Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

I would like to use the API for fetching reviews from Google Play Store:
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews/list

My expected flow to use this API:
1)User(Owner of the application) log in my application by his Google credentials
2)I get user's access_token
3)I use retrieved access_token for using API for fetching reviews.

But, when i tried to fetch reviews, i got following error:

```
 {
        "error": {
            "errors": [
                {
                    "domain": "androidpublisher",
                    "reason": "projectNotLinked",
                    "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console."
                }
            ],
            "code": 403,
            "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console."
        }
    }
```

So, i went to **Google Play Developer Console** and linked google play application to OAuth 2.0 project. And after that manipulation i was able to successfully get the reviews.

But some abstract user wouldn't be able to link his google play application with my OAuth 2.0 project. And for now, i just don't understand the reason, why Google added this restriction.

Is there any other way to fetch reviews for Google Play application(assuming that owner of that application can login using OAuth)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restriction is there because the API was not added so an arbitrary user can get details of app reviews for any developer. Instead it was added so that developers can write their own customer support tools for analyzing the reviews of their own customers and responding.

The same API is also used for things which are more serious than getting reviews, like publishing apps, and downloading financial data. Giving away Oauth access to your developer account is a risky thing to do. Google don't want to encourage developers to do it.